How to transform percentage form for variance decomposition
I have a data like this,
library(vars)
##### Step 1. dataframe #####
var_1 <- ts(c(0.0242964582, 0.0294573276, -0.0406138524, 0.0734349713, 0.2361871259, 0.2029464090, 
           -0.0674527667, -0.0865866204, -0.0677017382, 0.0064997957, 0.0306759752, -0.0348514188, 
           0.3077929490, 0.6501245473, 0.4040370401, 0.0367393504, -0.0939273959, -0.0059671701, 
           0.0004939013, -0.0368954264, 0.0189354253, -0.0295075205, -0.0144733327, 0.0594286409,
          -0.0067517162, -0.0211709703, 0.0296407577, 0.0020384478, -0.0783685670, 0.0467989571, 
           -0.0272364972, 0.1245476170, 0.2074924219, 0.0765883084, 0.0297613902, 0.1066229399, 
          0.1144391761, 0.0691379798, 0.0613940636, 0.0562433653, 0.0026634629, -0.0492358856,
          -0.0564408102, -0.0009823786, -0.0152348481))
var_2 <- ts(c(0.07180005, 0.18148396, 0.15866440, 0.17907557, 0.18708040, 0.22191278, 0.16989487, 
           0.07142307, 0.11280345, 0.10856817, 0.04717572, 0.15681239, 0.12041914, 0.07782770, 
           0.10910264, 0.10396963, 0.11468800, 0.11140086, 0.10013803, 0.08931388, 0.08638342, 
           0.08307560, 0.08056766, 0.07320740, 0.04571968, 0.05207004, -0.02045457, 0.04930865, 
           0.02719897, 0.05971614, 0.03727725, 0.04356057, 0.06103950, -0.01879438, -0.01503039, 
           0.08462488, 0.01425433, 0.02872101, 0.03960403, 0.06265019, 0.04786012, 0.02890597, 
           0.02409209, 0.02154608, 0.02988910))
var_3 <- ts(c(1.62, 0.81, 2.35, 2.06, 3.68, 7.89, 8.05, 1.70, 0.80, -0.01, -0.10, 0.42, 0.31, 0.78, 
           2.70, 2.64, 2.83, 2.98, 2.15, 2.84, 3.04, 2.32, 0.75, 1.23, 0.32, 1.01, -0.18, -0.17, 
           -0.16, 1.41, 1.62, 0.83, 1.63, 2.69, -0.39, 1.05, 1.29, 1.55, 0.99, 1.32, -0.59, 1.01, 
           1.09, 1.52, 0.56))
mydata <- cbind(var_1, var_2, var_3)
mydata <- as.data.frame(mydata)

I use SVAR model to analysis,
##### Step 2. SVAR Restrictions #####
# a. Diagonal Matrix
amat <- diag(3)
amat[lower.tri(amat)]<-NA
amat
# b. Lag Order Selection 
library(vars)
lagselect <- VARselect(mydata, lag.max = 3, type = "both")
lagselect$selection
# c. Estimating the Model # 
model_1 <- VAR(mydata, p=1, type="both") 
summary(model_1)
# Choleski decomposition
bmat <- diag(diag(chol(summary(model_1)$covres)), nrow=3, ncol=3, names=T) ###B
diag(bmat) <- NA
# svar, AB model #
svarmodel_1 <- SVAR(model_1, Amat=amat, Bmat=bmat, hessian=T, 
                    estmethod=c("scoring", "direct"), lrtest = F)
summary(svarmodel_1)

And when I try to see the plot of variance decomposition,
##### Step 3. variance decomposition #####
VD_svarmodel_1 <- fevd(svarmodel_1, n.head=10, rel = F)
plot(VD_svarmodel_1)

but I want percentage form in y axis,
so I try the code down below,
plot(VD_svarmodel_1, yaxt='n')
axis(2, at=pretty(VD_svarmodel_1), lab=pretty(VD_svarmodel_1) * 100, "%", las=TRUE)

it turns out "error in pretty.default(VD_svarmodel_1)：
'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double"
I have no idea, how can I fix it, I try to let percentage form in y axis? Thanks a lot!

You've got 3 panel layouts in the plot, so you can't just change all of them with one axis call.
I can't see any better way to do this, except to multiply all values of the model by 100 and then extend the y-axis limit (the default is c(0, 1) in the vars:::plot.varfevd function).
VD_svarmodel_1_pct <- lapply(VD_svarmodel_1, \(x) x*100)

You also have to change the class of the model object or the function will error.
class(VD_svarmodel_1_pct) <- "varfevd"

plot(VD_svarmodel_1_pct, ylim=c(0,100))



great! But how to add "%" on it?

I knew you would ask me that. Unfortunately, the answer is "I don't know" - maybe even "not possible, unless you do a lot of hacking of that function". Sorry!

You could plot each one separately..., then use your method.

Well it's okay, at least you solve me the half question, thanks.

Let me try - I may need a few minutes...

@CHIA Why adding %? The axis label already says percentage, it's redundant and only clutters the visualization. BTW you should accept and upvote the answer.

Yes - I agree with @jay,sf I think this would be overly complicated and I'm already running into problems trying to accomplish this.

yeah, I agree you both comments, but why mine y axis's number are straight?

I forgot to add plot(..., las=1)

great! thanks a lot, you solve my problems!
